# ISAPIRewrite.ini -IIRF

Tags: iirf

can any one help me with the regex and ini file my requiremnet is:

```
http://abc.com/Default.aspx must be redirected to http://def.com/test.aspx
http://abc.com/Default.aspx?tindex=1&sid=1 to http://def/com/test.aspx.
```

Comment: i have added the filter to the websites on my iis and copied the dll isaprewrite4.dll to inetpub directory and i have seen some examples for the stuff to go into the ini file but i didnot understand how to write the rewrite rules for my requirements